# Encoding and decoding with utf-8 returns UnicodeError

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, utf-8

I am both enconding and decoding with utf-8 but still I get a UnicodeError.

```
import pandas as pd
df.to_csv('myfile.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Then, in another .py, same project

```
import pandas as pd
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    csv = pd.read_csv(f, encoding='utf-8')
```

The error is:
**UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 51956: character maps to <undefined>**
This is not the first time I get this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it. Makes a lot of sense now.

```
with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    csv = pd.read_csv(f)
```